# Angular 8: unable to send Authorization with service

Tags: angular

I want to send the following "Authorization" through service.

```
Authorization :: Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==
```

In the service I wrote the following code:

```
constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.header_auth = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Authorization',  "Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==")
        }
    }

getToken() {
        return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + "oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=XXXXX&username=XX@XXX.com&grant_type=password", this.header_auth);
    }
```

I also used this code:
 `public basic: any = 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==';`

```
getToken() {

        const request = {
             headers: {
               'Authorization': this.basic,
             }
        };

        return this.http.post<any>(
            this.rootUrl + "oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=XXXXX&username=XX@XXX.com&grant_type=password",
            { headers: request.headers }
        );
}
```

When I called the service in my component, it shows me "error: "Unauthorized" But the same API URL is working well in "Postman".

**xxx.component.ts:**

```
this.commService.getToken().subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

In console I see the following error:

> POST http://10.X.X.XXX:8089/XXXX/oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=XXX&username=XX@XXX.com&grant_type=password 401

See postman screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to pass it:

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==' })
    };

return this.httpClient.post(this.rootUrl + "oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=XXXXX&username=XX@XXX.com&grant_type=password", httpOptions)
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'httpOptions'

Comment: If you are not using it in the same scope, use this.httpOptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
getToken() {
    return this.hc.post(`${this.rootUrl}oauth/token`, {}, {
      params: new HttpParams()
        .append('client_id', 'spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client')
        .append('password', 'XXXXX')
        .append('username', 'XX@XXX.com')
        .append('grant_type', 'password'),
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA=='),
    });
  }
```

You can try with HttpParams instead of manually query string.
[And also check this guide](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

Comment: Is your http method of API set to "Post"? Are you sure both are same http method?

Comment: Yes, post. Yes, http method

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to set headers. It is important to set the `Content-Type`

```
this.header_auth = {headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    Authorization: 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA=='
})};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.post(url, null, httpOptions)
```

I did the same as per the post [Angular 8: unable to set headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319526/angular-8-unable-to-set-headers/60319585#60319585)