# Angular 8: unable to set headers

Tags: angular

I want to call a service from my component:

```
getToken() {
  const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==' })};
  return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + "oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=root1234&username=tarak@bambootv.com&grant_type=password", httpOptions);
}
```

The call not showing the `Authorization`, check the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending the header as the request body.

You need to pass it as a third param to the call:

```
this.http.post(url, null, httpOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getToken() {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==',
        })
    };
    const Url = this.rootUrl + "oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=root1234&username=tarak@bambootv.com&grant_type=password";
    return this.http.post(Url,null, httpOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpInterceptor`

It will send token with every request.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA=='
      }
     });       
    return next.handle(request);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

send header as third params. Like

```
const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Basic c3ByaW5nLXNlY3VyaXR5LW9hdXRoMi1yZWFkLXdyaXRlLWNsaWVudDpzcHJpbmctc2VjdXJpdHktb2F1dGgyLXJlYWQtd3JpdGUtY2xpZW50LXBhc3N3b3JkMTIzNA==' })};
  return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + "oauth/token?client_id=spring-security-oauth2-read-write-client&password=root1234&username=tarak@bambootv.com&grant_type=password", {},httpOptions);
```